# how to read file name from folder by extension using command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have path for root folder. I want to get the file name with a ".txt" extension under that folder.

e.g.
my root path is "D:\SVN\ISG-RMG\Vendorpayment2.0\Branches\VPSAPITest\TestResults".

There are many files and sub-folders under this path.

I want to search for .txt file under given path and want to assign .txt file name to a variable in batch file and echo its name.

how to do?

Comment: got error "%%i was unexpected at this time."   and  "do set result" is command or its English sentence you want to write for me .Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run this as a batch file or from cmd?

Comment: i used cmd window to run your command. Do i save .bat  and run it?

Comment: From cmd use single `%` in batch use `%%`

Comment: Thanks I got the name . Now One modification I want. under the given path , one folder will be generated by my application, whose name is not known. but under newly generated folder I want to search .txt file and it should echo "newly folder name\txtfile.txt. can u suggest how to achieve it?

Comment: Your question was off topic to begin with, I posted an answer out of a favour. Randomly adding more requirenent changes is not how it works.

Comment: thank you. I had asked suggestion on top of it. but thanks for ur efforts

Comment: Well now you have working code. You can try with that to achieve your additional result. If you do not come right, ask a new question and show how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `cmd`

```
@for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /a-d "D:\SVN\ISG-RMG\Vendorpayment2.0\Branches\VPSAPITest\TestResults\*.txt"') do @set "result=%i"
```

In a batch file.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "D:\SVN\ISG-RMG\Vendorpayment2.0\Branches\VPSAPITest\TestResults\*.txt"') do set "result=%%i"
echo %result%
```

Answer (score -3):

The following commands searches for *.txt files in the /home/username/ directory and all sub-directories.

**Windows Command (this command is not tested as I am using Linux):**

```
dir /home/username/ *.txt
```

**Linux Command:**

```
find /home/username/ -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: but how will i store this file name in variable and echo it?

Comment: This not what the question asked for, even if it was your command will fail.

Comment: have you tried with windows command? sorry I can't able to test this command as I am using Linux. Linux command is tested.

Comment: As stated in my comment, the command for Windows will not work, it is also not an answer to the question as OP wants the result assigned to a variable. Yes, the Linux commands works, but this question is not related to linux and even if it was, it still does not assign the result to a variable.